# ExpressionEngine Safecracker Guest Thank you email

Tags: safecracker, email

Is it possible after submitting a safecracker form to send a thank you email to the guest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at the [Postmaster add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster) - it allows you to send fully-customizable email notifications after entries are submitted and/or edited (among other events).

(You'll have to make sure you collect the guest's email address as a custom field in your Safecracker form of course.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This seems like a great solution, but it is quite expensive. Is there no free way to do the same thing? Thanks

Comment: You can certainly write your own extension that utilizes the [safecracker_submit_entry_end hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/development.html#safecracker-submit-entry-end), extracting the entry info from the passed Safecracker object, then assembling and sending an email programatically ... but I'm betting that will take more than $65 of your time. :)